# How to verify a signature from the Phantom wallet?

Tags: javascript, java, blockchain, solana

I am able to sign a message on the client side using something like this:

```
const encodedMessage = new TextEncoder().encode("some message");
const signedMessage = await provider.signMessage(encodedMessage, "utf8");
```

Now I want to verify the signature on the back end side using Kotlin (or Java).

**Problem**:

1. I cannot find the information about the algorithm that is used for signing messages [in the documentation](https://docs.phantom.app/integrating/extension-and-in-app-browser-web-apps/signing-a-message).
2. It seems like there are no Java/Kotlin libraries that work with Phantom and Solana (found a few which are not updated for a year).

**Question**: How can I verify a signature from the Phantom wallet using Java? Or generally how can I do that in any language? (I will port it to Java then).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do it in Java or Kotlin is using [sol4k](https://github.com/sol4k/sol4k).

First, add it to your project (Gradle as an example):

```
implementation 'org.sol4k:sol4k:0.3.2'
```

Then call it from your Java code:

```
import org.sol4k.Base58;
import org.sol4k.PublicKey;
// ...
boolean verifySignature(String signature, String walletAddress) {
    String message = "signing message";
    byte[] messageBytes = message.getBytes();
    PublicKey publicKey = new PublicKey(walletAddress);
    byte[] signatureBytes = Base58.decode(signature);
    return publicKey.verify(signatureBytes, messageBytes);
}
```

Here, `signature` and `walletAddress` are Base58 encoded strings.

Frontend example how to get wallet address and the signature ([Phantom docs](https://docs.phantom.app/getting-started-with-solana/signing-a-message)):

```
const provider = window.phantom.solana;
const encodedMessage = new TextEncoder().encode('signing message');
const signedMessage = await provider.signMessage(encodedMessage, "utf8");
const base58 = await import("bs58");
const walletAddress = provider.publicKey.toString();
const signature = base58.encode(signedMessage.signature);
```

Here is [a blogpost](https://shpota.com/2023/05/04/how-to-verify-a-solana-wallet-signature-using-java.html) on the subject.

Answer (score 4):

I am not familiar with Kotlin or Java but here is how you can do it in other languages assuming the backend receives a `hex` encoded signature

### JS

```js
import { sign } from "tweetnacl";
sign.detached.verify(
    new TextEncoder().encode(message),
    new Uint8Array(Buffer.from(signed_message, "hex")),
    new PublicKey(pubkey_signer).toBytes()
  );
```

### Rust

```rust
use {
    hex,
    nacl::sign::verify,
    solana_program::pubkey::Pubkey,
};

// ...

verify(
    hex::decode(signed_message)
        .unwrap()
        .as_slice(),
    message.as_bytes(),
    &Pubkey::from_str(&address)
        .unwrap()
        .to_bytes(),
)
.unwrap();
```

### Go

```golang
import (
    "crypto/ed25519"
    "encoding/hex"

    "github.com/mr-tron/base58"
)

func verify(message string, signedMessage string, pubkey string) bool {
    bytes, err := base58.Decode(pubkey)
    if err != nil {
        return false
    }

    messageAsBytes := []byte(message)

    signedMessageAsBytes, err := hex.DecodeString(signedMessage)
    if err != nil {
        return false
    }

    return ed25519.Verify(bytes, messageAsBytes, signedMessageAsBytes)
}
```

### Python

```py
import base58
from nacl.signing import VerifyKey

def verify_message(message: bytes, signed_message: str, address: str) -> bool:
    address_bytes = base58.b58decode(address)
    vk = VerifyKey(address_bytes)
    try:
        vk.verify(message, bytes.fromhex(signed_message))
        return True
    except:
        return False
```